# URL Anchor Text Regular Expression Puller

Tags: java, regex

So I'm trying to figure out a regular expression that simply will not work for me. I've never been very good at writing them, and was hoping somebody could explain what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to pull anchor text from HREFs with Java. I've got it downloading the page I'm looking to get the text from fine, but for some reason it won't strip the things I need it to. On every page, the class and title don't change - in fact, I only want the ones with that specific class and title.

```
s = <span class="alwaysTheSameClass"><a title="alwaysTheSameTitle" href="differentEveryTime">TextImTryingToPull</span><br>
s = s.replace(,""<span class=\"alwaysTheSameClass\"><a title=\"alwaysTheSameTitle\" href=\".*\">"")
```

Every time I do this, it prints up the same. I did an `s.contains` but it comes up false. As I said, I'm horrible with regular expressions - I thought this one might be simple enough to use, but apparently I was wrong. Where's my problem here?

Thanks guys!

Comment: `java` != `javascript`, also `I'm trying to figure out a regular expression that simply will *not* work for me`... are you sure?

Comment: Well as I said, I'm using Java. I can't seem to get it to work in Eclipse. Any thoughts would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems, first you are missing the close anchor tag `</a>` in your example. In your regex you'll need to escape any `/` characters so they'll look like `\/`. Your `string.replace` statement looks like it's missing the what-to-search-for portion [see java manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

## Description

This regex will find all anchor tags where the title attribute is `alwaysTheSameTitle`. The expression does require the attributes' value be surrounded by either single or double quotes. Once this is found the expression will capture the href attribute value and the string between the open and close anchor text. This expression will allow the href and title attributes to appear in the anchor tag in any order.

`<a\b(?=\s)(?=[^>]*\s\btitle=(["'])alwaysTheSameTitle\1)(?=[^>]*\s\bhref=(["'])((?:(?!\2)|.)*)\2)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>`

[image]

## Groups

Group 0 will have the entire anchor tag from open tag to close tag

1. will have the open quote type either single or double, this is used at `\1` to validate you have the correct closing character arond the `title` attribute value
2. will have the open quote type either single or double, this is used at `\2` to validate you have the correct closing character arond the `href` attribute value
3. will have the href attribute value string, not including the quotes
4. will have the string wrapped inside the anchor tag

## Match example

Given input text `<span class="alwaysTheSameClass"><a title="alwaysTheSameTitle" href="differentEveryTime">TextImTryingToPull</a></span><br>`

Matches

```
[0] => <a title="alwaysTheSameTitle" href="differentEveryTime">TextImTryingToPull</a>
[1] => "
[2] => "
[3] => differentEveryTime
[4] => TextImTryingToPull
```

## Disclaimer

The inner text should really be pulled out using an html parsing engine, this will avoid problematic edge cases where a regex parsing HTML text will fail. However providing you're in control of the HTML and/or you're willing to accept the risk of rare edge cases consisting of obscure, rare, or illegal html where this expression won't work as expected then a regex will likely work for you

Answer (score 0):

Getting your answer from the DOM would be a lot easier.  For example:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
for (foo in links){
if(links[foo].title = "always the same"){
var bar = links[foo].href; //this should get your href
alert(bar);
}
}
```

Cheers,
LC